# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).cytoscape is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, cytoscape.js

I found this code on Internet and it works :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/cytoscape.js"></script>

   <div id="cy"></div>
    <script>
       $(function(){ // on dom ready

$('#cy').cytoscape({
  style: cytoscape.stylesheet()
    .selector('node')
      .css({
        'content': 'data(deneme)'
      })
```

I changed this code to the code below (I basically moved that code block inside success part of an ajax call) :

```
  $("form").submit(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "/MyController/MyAction",
           data: { nameid: $('#nameid').val() },
            success: function (newdata) {

                $('#cy').cytoscape({
                    layout: {
```

And it gives this error :

```
> MainGraph:55 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).cytoscape is not a function
>     at Object.success (MyCode:55)
>     at i (jquery.min.js:2)
>     at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
>     at A (jquery.min.js:4)
>     at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:4)
```

How can I make this work? I tried changing code to this :

```
var cy = cytoscape({
  container: $('#cy'),
```

The error above goes away but then it fails in other parts. How can I solve this situation? Thanks.

Comment: Probably a race condition, make sure cytoscape.js is loaded at the moment of call. (after jQuery, before everything else though)

Comment: @SamuilPetrov There are two external js files in my code, first is jQuery, second is cytoscape.js. I added them to my question .Thanks.

Comment: Do you include cytoscape.js before this script ?

Comment: The link to the cytoscape.js is wrong. You can't link to it like that. You need to use a relative path. If the Scripts folder is in the same directory as the webpage, you need to use `/Scripts/cytoscape.js` as `src`

Comment: @DouwedeHaan It's not wrong, it's how you do it in ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: @jason The error you posted looks like one that is thrown in the browser, correct? Check if your browser can find the file, because I doubt it.

Comment: @DouwedeHaan It finds the file, it's how it looks in the browser: `<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/cytoscape.js"></script>`. Thanks

Comment: @jason Fair enough! Would be smart to tag your question with the ASP.NET MVC tag and include it in the question, so others know that you use ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: try to delay your script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `$(el).cytoscape()` function.  You do `let cytoscape = require('cytoscape'); let cy = cytoscape();` or `let Cytoscape = require('cytoscape'); let cy = new Cytoscape();`]

There often no need to put the cy init in a callback.  Just specify `elements` as a promise and Cytoscape handles the rest.